# Linux driver access through sysfs

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, sysfs

I'm making a small kernel module to provide user-space access to some kernel-mode only features of an ARMv7 chip (specifically, cache control). I'm reading through **Linux Device Drivers** by Corbet, Rubini, and Hartman. In it they describe how to make a full driver+device+bus. I don't want to create a bus driver at all. In fact the 'driver' that I'm making doesn't really need to match against a device definition at all - it is implicitly matched to the platform's CPU. Can anyone explain to me:

1. Where in sysfs should my attributes go? Should it be in my module entry under `/sysfs/modules/mymodule`? `/sys/devices/platform` seems promising too, and so does `/sys/devices/system/cpu`.
2. If there is an existing place where I should put my `kobject`/attributes, how do I plug it into it? How do I get the necessary `kset`? All the examples I've seen create a `kset` and then link to it from the `kobject` - I haven't seen an API for requesting an existing named `kset`?

Sorry if this is just impossibly obvious, or if there's some really straightforward and easily discovered example somewhere that I haven't discovered for some reason. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't worked with sysfs much, but I found a simple-looking example that's pretty similar to what you are doing (naturally, it's also under ARM). Take a look at `arch/arm/mach-omap1/pm.c`, specifically the `idle_show`/`idle_store` sysfs file. It gets registered (using `sysfs_create_file()`) as `/sys/power/sleep_while_idle` and uses the global `/sys/power` kobj (defined in `include/linux/kobject.h`). There are a few other global kobj's defined there that you could use, although I'm don't think any are a good fit for your driver.

Is this going to be a platform driver? As a driver that doesn't fit under any bus, it seems like a good fit. Platform drivers get their own directory under /sys/devices/platform, and can have attributes there. Take a look at `drivers/hwmon/coretemp.c`, which has `temp1_crit`, `temp1_crit_alarm`, `temp1_input`, etc. as attributes. It looks fairly simple: create the attributes (maybe with `__ATTR()`?), list them all in an array, define an `attribute_group`, register it with `sysfs_create_group()` in the `probe()` function, and unregister it with `sysfs_remove_group()` in the `remove()` function.

There are probably other platform drivers that define attributes (search for `sysfs_create_group`) if you need other examples. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'll have a look at the coretemp.c driver. Thanks!

Comment: An update - the coretemp module was the perfect template. I got some sysfs attributes working quite nicely. Thanks again.